# IO redirection in Linux

Tags: linux, redirect, io

I'm executing a c file and writing to the output to a file in the following format.

```
./test >> foo.csv
12245933        1
46909645052845  2
46909767324372  3
```

However, when I run it without writing to a file, the output is the following.

```
./test

12245933        1
46909645052845  2
134517460       3
```

Note the information i'm dumping is a uint64.

what is wrong? what is the mistake i'm doing?
am i using the wrong io redirection?

Comment: Please include the source of `test` in your question, if that is possible.

Comment: I'm doing the following
`cout<<blah<<endl;`
where blah is a `uint64`.

Comment: If you want us to help you in the diagnosis of your problem, please provide the information we asked, not the information you think we need. So, post the source of `test`, or wait for another guy.